# PySpark + sentence-transformers - UDF cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sentence-transformers

I would like to use PySpark and the library sentence-transformers to speed up the embedding of a corpus of documents.

From what I understand I can't just call :

```
embedd_text = udf(lambda x: model.encode(x).tolist(), ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))
```

Because the model can't be pickled and be passed to the workers.

That's why I put the code that way:

```
class text_embedder:
    @property
    def model(self):
        return SentenceTransformer('dangvantuan/sentence-camembert-large')
        
    def embedd_text(self, x):
        return self.model.encode(x).tolist()
    
    def return_embedd_text_column(self, df):
        embedd_text_udf = udf(self.embedd_text, returnType=ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))
        return df.withColumn("text_embedded", embedd_text_udf(data.text))
```

That way, the model should be created within the UDF call and distributed to the workers.

The problem is now I'm facing `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object` and I don't know where the problem comes from.

My question is: is it possible to do what I try to do, if yes, is it a good idea to do it like that performance-wise.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the model in the udf each executor node needs to have the model available.
you can use [Broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Broadcast.html#pyspark.Broadcast) in order to send the model to each executor.
Then in the udf, instead of calling model you will need to call the `broadcast_variable.value` which is the model.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *


df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (["This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence"],),
    (["Sentences are passed as a list of string"],),
    (["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"],),
], schema=["sentence"])

broadcast_model = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(model)

embedd_text = udf(lambda x: broadcast_model.value.encode(x).tolist(), ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))

df.withColumn("embedded", embedd_text("sentence")).show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|            sentence|            embedded|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[This framework g...|[[-0.013717361, -...|
|[Sentences are pa...|[[0.06387022, 0.0...|
|[The quick brown ...|[[0.035496805, 0....|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```